# Como recargar una fecha de un "input type date" con ajax

Tags: jquery, html5, php7

tengo el siguiente código.

```
<form class="" action="vista2.php" method="post">
<label style="display:block; overflow:hidden;">Fecha de conciliacion</label>
<input type="date" id="fecha" name="echa">
<input type="submit" name="Insertar"   value="Buscar conciliacion">
</form>
```

el cual manda una fecha especifica al seleccionarla en el calendario y enviarla
mediante un botón (con el `action ="vista2.php"`) hace la referencia de la vista
a la que manda la fecha.

en `vista2.php` tengo.

```
$fecha= $_POST['echa'];
$newDate = date("Y/m/d", strtotime($fecha));

echo "$newDate";
```

funciona correctamente ya que recibo la fecha la acomodo a mi gusto y la imprimo

mi pregunta es 
¿Como puedo enviar la fecha a un formulario distinto con ajax sin necesidad del `action`?
dentro del otro formulario tengo un método donde cachare la fecha y ejecutare otra vista

¿como seria la estructura del código en ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Con jQuery:

```
function guardar(){

    var campos = {
            "fecha" : $("#fecha").val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
            data:  campos,
            url:   'tuarchivo.php',
            type:  'post',
            success:  function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
    }); 

}
```

El HTML:

```
<form class="" action="vista2.php" method="post">
    <label style="display:block; overflow:hidden;">Fecha de conciliacion</label>
    <input type="date" id="fecha" name="echa">
    <input  name="Insertar"   value="Buscar conciliacion" onclick="guardar()">
</form>
```